# passing parameter to overlaypanel jsf2

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I use spring with `JSF-2 and primefaces`.

I have the relation `OneToMany` between `Filiale` and `Commentaire`.
I need to add `Commentaire`.
But i have problem to pass the `id of Filiale`.

I have the following code:

```
<f:param name="idFiliale" value="#{filialeBean.details.filiale}" ></f:param>
        <f:viewParam id ="id" name="idFiliale" ></f:viewParam>

                    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

....

```
<p:commandButton id="commentBtn" value="Dynamic" type="button" >
```

```
<p:overlayPanel id="commentPanel" for="commentBtn" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" style="width:600px">

    <p:panel header="Nouveau Commentaire" style="width:450px;height:250px;border:none;font-size:small;padding:0px;" >

        <h:form>
             <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="date" value="Date:" />
    <p:calendar id="date" value="#{commentaireBean.comment_date}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />

                <h:outputText for="text" value="Commentaire:" />

    <h:inputTextarea value="#{commentaireBean.comment_text}"></h:inputTextarea>

                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Ajouter Commentaire"
                    action="#{commentaireBean.addCommentaire(idFiliale)}" >
                    <f:param  name="idFiliale" value="#{idFiliale}"></f:param>
                    </h:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>



@Component("commentaireBean")
@Scope("session")
public class CommentaireBean {

    @Autowired
    private CommentaireService commentService;

    @Autowired
    FilialeService filialeService;

String idfiliale= (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("idFiliale" );

public void addCommentaire(Long filiale_id){
        commentaire = new Commentaire();
             commentaire.setComment_text( getComment_text() );

             Long id = Long.parseLong(idfiliale);
             System.out.println("id" + id);

             commentaire.setFiliale( filialeService.getFiliale(id ));
            commentaire.setComment_date( comment_date );
          System.out.println("avant d'ajourer");
             commentService.addCommentaire( commentaire );
             System.out.println("après d'ajourer");

             FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage( "Ajout de commentaire reussi!" );
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null, message );
              }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:453)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
at com.ant.pbacklog.managedbean.FilialeBean.getFiliale_id(FilialeBean.java:102)
at com.ant.pbacklog.managedbean.FilialeBean.getCommentaires(FilialeBean.java:227)
```

Comment: Don't post trace as comment, instead edit in your post.

Comment: Done , it's my first question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your `idFiliale` object has to have a getter and setter. Then you can just do:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Ajouter Commentaire"
    action="#{commentaireBean.addCommentaire(idFiliale)}" >
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{idFiliale}" target="#{filialeBean.idFiliale}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thank you i tested your answer in fact in the scoped variables i have the idfiliale but i have this error: /pages/FilialeDetails.xhtml @61,88 <f:serPropertyActionListener> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: serPropertyActionListener

Comment: I'm so sorry, I wrote the answer on my phone, I meant to say `f:setPropertyActionListener`